# How to solve the circular dependency in angular 11

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, circular-dependency

I have a loggerService which logs all messages to a backend system via BackendService including the IP of the device, which it get from the IpService:

```
LoggerService injects IpService and BackendService
```

The problem is, that the services IpService and BackendService should also be able to log errors via the LoggerService:

```
IpService injects LoggerService
BackendService injects LoggerService
```

How can I solve this particular problem?

If there is no way to solve this issue, I am looking for a way to ignore the warning in angular for this particular circular dependency but warnong me when there are other circular dependencies found.

Answer (score 0):

As an option, you can use an `Injector`:

```
  constructor(private injector: Injector) { }

   func() {
     const auth = this.injector.get(LoggerService);
     //... do something
   }
```

But, the fact that you've faced that error may be giving you a hint that something is wrong with your current architecture. I don't see your code but in my mind, `LoggerService` should only do logging and do not use `IpService` and `BackendService` as dependencies.

Comment: thanks, I have tried the injector, but angular still finds the  circular dependencies, this might have worked in former versions of angular

Answer (score 0):

What I did is the following to solve the circular dependecy which is really necessary.
Do not ignore those warnings!

I removed the LoggerService from IpService and BackendService because when these Services throw an Error which is supposed to belogged, you end with an endless call stack letting the browser freeze and destroy your application.